# How to read a large value of type REG_DWORD from the registry?

Tags: c#, registry

I have the following method:

```
public static object GetRegValue(RegistryHive hive, string subKey, string key)
{
    try
    {
        var view32 = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(hive,
                                RegistryView.Default);
        using (var regKey = view32.OpenSubKey(subKey, false))
        {
            return regKey.GetValue(key, 0);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Logger.Log($"Get {subKey} + {key} from Registry failed");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And I use it whenever I need to access a certain registry path.
However, I found a bug in the following code segment while accessing 0xa8200410 (2820670480)

```
Convert.ToUInt64(GetRegValue(RegistryHive.CurrentUser, RegistryPath, RegistryKeyName));
```

I see that from `GetValue()` I get `Int32` value. It gives me some large negative value. So I searched for ways to convert that into `ulong`.

```
var value = 0ul;
unchecked
{
    value = (ulong)(int)Misc.GetRegValue(RegistryHive.CurrentUser, RegistryPath, RegistryKeyName);
}
```

Still, it gave me the wrong value.

Can anyone give me an idea on approaching for getting a large DWORD value from the registry in C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 2820670480 value is an unsigned integer. When it's cast to an `int`, you get a negative value. So, you need to cast it to `uint`. However, the `GetValue()` method returns a boxed value **whose underlying type is `int`**. If you try to cast it directly to a `uint`, it won't work:

```
// This will throw an InvalidCastException
int value = (uint)GetRegValue(RegistryHive.CurrentUser, RegistryPath, RegistryKeyName);
```

You need to unbox it (by casting it to an `int`) first, and then convert it to a `uint`:

```
int temp = (int)GetRegValue(RegistryHive.CurrentUser, 
                            RegistryPath, RegistryKeyName); //-1474296816
int value = (uint)temp; // 2820670480
```

Or you can still do it in one statement:

```
int value = (uint)(int)GetRegValue(RegistryHive.CurrentUser, 
                                   RegistryPath, RegistryKeyName);
```

You can *then* cast it to a `ulong` (AKA, `UInt64`) but that's not necessary. A DWORD cannot have a value larger than 32 bits anyway.

Comment: Thanks. I presumably  knew `GetValue()` returns an `Int32` value, but never thought of explicitly casting the value three times. (I've only tried `(ulong) (int)`) I managed to handle the case by setting it as you mentioned. `(ulong) (uint) (int) GetRegValue()`

Comment: @vaska11 As I mentioned above, you don't _need_ to cast to `ulong`. You should only do that if you need to have the value stored in a 64-bit integer for some other reason. Note that if you were dealing with QWORD, you'd cast like this `(ulong)(long)GetRegValue()` because `GetValue()` returns a boxed `long` in that case. You still don't _need_ to cast three times.